# Add appointment after user select date from embed calendar - and save reference

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there a way to add new appointment after user select a date from Google Embed Calendar, so user can see all existing appointment to help him choose the right day!

Another thing, after saving the new appointment, is there a way to add to that appointment, a reference to my app - so when user view that appointment he could click on that reference to open new browser window with my app.

See included [demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNdSa.png).

Thank You.

Comment: As mentioned in this related [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/CTKHyKn6dRI), embedded calendar is only for display and adding of events from Google Embed Calendar is currently not supported yet. You may want to check this [article](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/calendar-services/create-calendar-events-by-submitting-form) and this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845769/add-event-to-embedded-google-calendar) for other options.

Comment: Or, you may want to also file a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Classroom).

Comment: 1, I have send feature request

Comment: Why google not give to applications the option to use embed calendar with full data synchronization - I don't want to have third party calendar that will synchronized with google calendar with google api, why? I love google ui, why to use other? Thank you.